# Getting 404 in place of 401 response when I remove AllowAnonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to .net core and while developing the authorization was working. However, not sure what changed in between but now I am getting 404 inplace of 401 when I remove AllowAnonymous.

Below is my configuration:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        //Identity
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<SolUser,IdentityRole> (opt => 
            {
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail =true;
            
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<StudentDBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xx"));
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt => 
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = key,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });


        builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
        // End of Identity    

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDBContext>();

        builder.Services.AddCors(opt => 
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>{
            policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
             policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("X");
                policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("X");
            });
        });


        builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler));

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        // With below we dont have to authorize at get/post level. AllowAnonymous will allow for login and register

        builder.Services.AddControllers(opt => 
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfiles).Assembly);

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailService,EmailService>();
        builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
        builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<SolStudent>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();  //Top of the Middleware stack

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        //Identity order important
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();



        app.MapControllers();
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

        app.Run();
```

Below is my controller. If I add allowanonymous then it works. But once I remove it and even if I pass the token I get 404

```
namespace netreact.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProgramController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ProgramController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            //_context = context;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }


        public JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
                {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
                WriteIndented = true
                };

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<TrialProgram>>> GetList()
        
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(new TrialProg.Query());
        }
```

Comment: 404 means not found. Are you sure you are hitting the endpoint when authorisation is in place? My guess would be the authorisation blocks before. Please share how you are you calling the endpoint.

Comment: Yes....it was not hitting the endpoint. Addming below made it work.
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My Identity was conflicting with Authentication and once I added below in ** it worked. Please note my AddIdentity is above AddAuthentication.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                **options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;**
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(...)
```